# HADOOP / YARN - Are the ResourceManager and the hdfs NameNode always installed on the same host?

Tags: apache, rest, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, webhdfs

Are the “resource manager” and the “hdfs namenode” always installed on the same host?

1)  When I want to send an http request (YARN REST API) to [get new application id](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_New_Application_API) I am using this web uri:

```
http://<rm http address:port>/ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application
```

This port is the Resource-Manager Web UI http port, it’s default value is 8088 as shown in img1: [source for img1](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDP2Alpha/index.htm#Appendix/Ports_Appendix/YARN_Ports.htm)[image: Yarn Ports]

2)  When I want to send an http request (WebHDFS REST API) for hdfs commands, for example to [get file status](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Status_of_a_FileDirectory) I am using this web uri:

```
http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=GETFILESTATUS
```

This `<PORT>` is the NameNode WebUI http Port, it’s default value is 50070 as shown in img2: [source for img2](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDP2Alpha/index.htm#Appendix/Ports_Appendix/HDFS_Ports.htm)
[image: HDFS Ports]

Are the hosts of those components (ResourceManager and NaneNode) are always installed on the same host?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You can install the YARN Resource Manager and the HDFS Namenode to any host you like. They don't need to share the host.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not necessary to run resourceManager and nameNode on a single machines, we have such configuration when working in a single node/small cluster---with few nodes---configuration. When there is large cluster, master nodes usually run resourceManager, nameNode and secondaryNamenode on different machines.

[image: cluster topology]

Have a look at these links:

[Master Nodes in Hadoop Clusters](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/master-nodes-in-hadoop-clusters.html)

[HortonWorks: Typical Hadoop Cluster](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_cluster-planning-guide/content/typical-hadoop-cluster-hardware.html)

Comment: The note says that Datanodes, NodeManagers, regionservers are co-deployed. Do you mean that each worker node has a datanode, a nodemanager and a regionserver ?!